# 'watch' is not interpreting the implicit 'reset' color code `^[m`

Tags: ubuntu, ansi-escape, procps

It appears that `watch` is not interpret the implicit 'reset' color code `^[m`. It does interpret the *explicit* code `^[0m`.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Or does it sound like a bug and I need to contact the maintainers of `watch`?

### Why I'm asking:

I'm using `watch` with `git log`, and `git log` uses implicit resets `^[m`.

Example:

```
$ watch -c git log --oneline --decorate --source --graph --color=always
```

[image: showing the issue]

What it should look like is:

```
$ git log --oneline --decorate --source --graph --color=always
```

[image: expected]

### Investigation

If we don't include the `-c` (`--color`) option on `watch`, we can see that the ANSI escape codes are there:

```
Every 2.0s: git log --oneline --decorate --source --graph --color=always                                                                                                                                                                               Fri Sep 28 08:17:42 2018

* ^[33m9db218b^[m       HEAD^[33m (^[m^[1;36mHEAD^[m^[33m -> ^[m^[1;32mmaster^[m^[33m, ^[m^[1;33mtag: v0.8.0b5^[m^[33m, ^[m^[1;31morigin/master^[m^[33m, ^[m^[1;31morigin/HEAD^[m^[33m)^[m Doc updates for v0.8.0b5 release
* ^[33mfd342d9^[m       HEAD Update changelog [ci skip]
* ^[33md1af865^[m       HEAD Update changelog
*   ^[33m70889fa^[m     HEAD Merge branch 'testing-updates' into 'master'
```

There's a lot going on in the above example - let's simplify it:

#### Prove that we're escaping things correctly:

```
$ echo -e "\033[33myellow\033[mnormal"
```

[image: simple echo color escaping]

#### Send it to `watch`

Note: the `-e` arg on `echo` is not parsed because we're quoting things. `watch` now handles the color codes.

```
$ watch -c 'echo -e "\033[33myellow\033[mnormal"'
```

[image: watch fails with the reset code]

#### Remove the `-c` flag from `watch`

```
$ watch 'echo -e "\033[33myellow\033[mnormal"'
Every 2.0s: echo -e "\033[33myellow\033[mnormal"      Fri Sep 28 08:29:26 2018

-e ^[33myellow^[mnormal
```

This looks as expected.

#### Using the explicit `^[0m` reset code works

```
$ watch -c 'echo -e "\033[33myellow\033[0mnormal"'
```

[image]

### Versions

Primarily tested under WSL: Window 10 Pro, v1803, build 17134.286

```
$ watch -v
watch from procps-ng 3.3.10
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
$ uname -a
Linux redacted-hostname 4.4.0-17134-Microsoft #285-Microsoft Thu Aug 30 17:31:00 PST 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ git --version
git version 2.7.4
```

Also tested using PuTTY to a linux machine. Same version information as above, just not using WSL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was fixed in version 3.3.12 of `procps`, which contains `watch`:

https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/issues/12

https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/commit/6fcb690099bd681930946492e8a93c61e82249d8